# Docker swarm certificates

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I tried to follow the [Docker Operations](https://training.docker.com/docker-operations) tutorial, I worked around most of Docker Machine and Compose since I am on a Windows machine, but couldn't successfully get to use Swarm.

I got stuck because it kept asking for some certificates (`ca.pem` file) when I tried to join an instance to the cluster. I also noticed that on `docker-machine create ...` on the tutors machine the first line that got printed on to the screen had to do with copying or generating certificates, my Docker Machine does none of that.

Is this because I am on a Windows machine? Does the tutor have access to some nightly build that works correctly? Or do I have to learn how to generate these certificates elsewhere?

Disclaimer: I know very little about IT stuff, Docker has been an excellent way of setting up my Digital Ocean droplet without really installing anything.

Comment: Probably you've moved on from that already, but to anyone with that question if you can run docker-machine you already have its certificates configured so just execute `docker-machine config [name of the machine]` to see where the certificate files are and just configure Swarm to point at them.